# RCPTT : ECL command to get the product install path

Tags: eclipse-rcptt

There is a use case in my application that some file will downloaded in the product installed path . I need check these files are downloaded from the remote . so i need to get the product install path (not workspace)

I need to get `Platform.getInstallLocation().getURL().getPath()`

Answer (score 0):

Since RCPTT does not provide a standard ECL command to return the AUT location, you will need to create your own custom ECL command. This command will invoke `Platform.getInstallLocation().getURL()` and return the corresponding uri as a string.